# How to set @click dynamically in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have array of objects, where action is method from vue object.

How to set `@click` dynamically in v-for cycle?

I tried to use this.m1, "this.m1", "m1", but i'm getting an error:

> fns.apply is not a function.

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { title: "Learn JavaScript", action: this.m1 },
      { title: "Learn Vue", action: "m2" },
      { title: "Play around in JSFiddle", action: "this.m3"},
      { title: "Build something awesome", action: "m4"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    m1() {
        console.log('1');
    },
    m2() {
        console.log('2');
    },
    m3() {
        console.log('3');
    },
    m4() {
        console.log('4');
    },
  }
})
```

Html:

```
<div id="app">
   <div v-for="item in items">
       <a @click="item.action" href="#">
         {{ item.title }}
       </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/mezhevikin/eywraw8t/338303/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store the method names in the action property, like `action: "m1"`, you can pass those names to a method (let's say `invokeMethod`) via `"invokeMethod(item.action)"`. Now, within this `invokeMethod`, you can invoke the relevant functions by invoking  `this[methodName]()` - where `this[methodName]` is equivalent to saying `this["m1"]`.

```js
var app=new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { title: "Learn JavaScript", action: "m1" },
      { title: "Learn Vue", action: "m2" },
      { title: "Play around in JSFiddle", action: "m3"},
      { title: "Build something awesome", action: "m4"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    invokeMethod(methodName) {
        this[methodName]();
    },
    m1() {
        console.log('1');
    },
    m2() {
        console.log('2');
    },
    m3() {
        console.log('3');
    },
    m4() {
        console.log('4');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
   <div v-for="item in items">
       <a @click="invokeMethod(item.action)" href="#">
         {{ item.title }}
       </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be a function

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: "Learn JavaScript", action: this.m1 },
        { title: "Learn Vue", action: this.m2 },
        { title: "Play around in JSFiddle", action: this.m3},
        { title: "Build something awesome", action: this.m4}
     ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    m1() {
        console.log('1');
    },
    m2() {
        console.log('2');
    },
    m3() {
        console.log('3');
    },
    m4() {
        console.log('4');
    }
  }
})
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/ojdz0r41/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass item object in a single method , then you do operation as per your requirement.

```js
var app=new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { title: "Learn JavaScript", action: "m1" },
      { title: "Learn Vue", action: "m2" },
      { title: "Play around in JSFiddle", action: "m3"},
      { title: "Build something awesome", action: "m4"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    callmethod(item) {
        console.log(item.action);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
   <div v-for="item in items">
       <a @click="callmethod(item)" href="#">
         {{ item.title }}
       </a>
   </div>
</div>
```